# x-editable combodate: Allow both date and datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, x-editable

I am using http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html.  If the user selects a date but not a time on the datetime element, I would like to update the value with just the date, and either send just the date or the date with `00:00` time to the server.  As seen by http://jsfiddle.net/vgybLp6j/1/, it will set to an `empty` value if time is not given.

```
$('#datetime').editable({
    type: 'combodate',
    title: 'Select date and time',
    template: "D MMM YYYY  HH:mm",
    viewformat: "DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm",
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
    url: '/post',
    pk:1
});

$('#date').editable({
    type: 'combodate',
    title: 'Select Date',
    template: "D MMM YYYY",
    viewformat: "DD/MM/YYYY",
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    url: '/post',
    pk:1
});

<p>datetime</p>
<div style="margin-left: 300px">
    <a href="#" id="datetime">04/05/2010, 05:30</a>
</div>
<p>datetime</p>
<div style="margin-left: 300px">
    <a href="#" id="date">04/05/2010</a>
</div>
```